# SPL InfiniteIterator is not working with next or prev

Tags: php, iterator, infinite-loop, php-7.2, spl

I wanted to over an array infinitely like a circular array.

I have the following setup using `InfiniteIterator`[1](http://php.net/manual/en/class.infiniteiterator.php), which iterates over the `$players` infinitely. But actually, I want to know the next player and the previous player from this loop like below

```
$players = new InfiniteIterator(new ArrayIterator(['Shobi', 'Jomit']));

foreach ($players as $player) {
    echo $player; // current player name comes properly infinetly
    echo next($players); // next player should come
    echo current($players); // current player should come
    echo prev($players); //previous player should come
}
```

but `next()` and `prev()` always return null

From the doc, I can see those methods are returning void, but is there any way I can extend the InfiniteIterator and achieve this mechanism required?

How do I make `next()` and `prev()` work with InfiniteIterator?

**Edit** `current()` returns current item, (meaning, it works properly in the logic)

Comment: Do you need to use `InfiniteIterator` or would an alternative do?

Comment: alternative would do, only thing is i need to be able to iterate over it infinitely, I found InfiniteIterator in the first hand, So I thought to use it :)

Answer (score 1):

If instead of using iterators, you can just use an array and a pointer to the 'current' entry and then use a `while(true)` loop which will just keep going (you can always add a `break` to stop it for testing or some condition).  The various parts of the logic check if the current player is the last one - so the next one is the start one - 
 or if it's the first item so the previous is the end item.  Also the increment resets once it gets to the end and starts over again...

```
$players = ['Shobi', 'Jomit'];
$playerKey = 0;
$playerCount = count($players);
while(true) {
    echo $players[($playerKey+1)%$playerCount].PHP_EOL; // next player
    echo $players[$playerKey].PHP_EOL; // current player
    echo $players[($playerKey>0)?$playerKey-1:$playerCount-1].PHP_EOL; //previous player
    $playerKey = ( $playerKey+1 == $playerCount )?0:$playerKey+1;
}
```

Comment: sorry for the delayed response, In fact, this is the first solution I have come up with, but it looks a bit muddy, therefore I have tried to use a cleaner looking solution at least. +1 though

Comment: If you've solved it your own way then post an answer so that others may learn from it.

Comment: Sure, I will post in a moment

Answer (score 1):

You can go nuts with PHP iterators and do something like the following:

```
$array = ['Shobi', 'Jomit', 'John', 'Jane', 'Smith'];

// Use NoRewindIterator to prevent MultipleIterator rewinding.
$players1 = new NoRewindIterator(new InfiniteIterator(new ArrayIterator($array)));
// Go to the end of array, i.e. set prev player.
for ($i = 0, $size = count($array); $i < $size - 1; $i++) {
    $players1->next();
}

$players2 = new InfiniteIterator(new ArrayIterator($array));
$players2->next();

// Use NoRewindIterator to prevent MultipleIterator rewinding.
$players3 = new NoRewindIterator(new InfiniteIterator(new ArrayIterator($array)));
$players3->next(); // Go to the second player, i.e. next player

// MultipleIterator will traverse three iterators at once.
// Since the pointer in each iterator differs in one position, we will have prev, curr and next.
$players = new MultipleIterator(MultipleIterator::MIT_NEED_ALL|MultipleIterator::MIT_KEYS_ASSOC);
$players->attachIterator($players1, 'prev');
$players->attachIterator($players2, 'curr');
$players->attachIterator($players3, 'next');

$i = 0;
foreach ($players as $player) {
    print_r($player);

    if (++$i >= 10) {
        break;
    }
}
```

Please, see [the demo](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/387d9579686f5b41951709d9bb3a453cd5d7de71).

Comment: that's a lot of iterators :P, Actually, I implemented Iterator interface and tweaked the `next()` and `prev()` methods to `rewind` and `reset`the underlying array appropriately. Will post an answer soon

Comment: @Shobi, please, take into an account that `next` and `prev` methods have a side effect -- they move the internal pointer. That's why they do not return anything by design and have `void` return type. Using those methods to get a value triggers side effect and make the code unpredictable

Comment: Yep,  extending builtin classes and modifiying the methods is a bad practice as well as per my understanding. But I am not returning anything from there, even I did it will get ignored as per the documentation

Comment: Would you mind takign a look here ? https://gist.github.com/ppshobi/5d4da801fac3be866ea617a5d9637cca

Answer (score 0):

Posting an answer which I finally came up with.

The infinite iterator was not really working for my case. Especially because I was not able to move the pointer back using the `prev()` function. So I did implement the [Iterator Interface](http://php.net/manual/en/class.iterator.php) and override the `next` and `prev` methods accordingly.

So that when `next()` is  called and if it is at the end of the array, it will rewind the pointer to the beginning, likewise, if `prev()` is called and the pointer is already at the beginning, it will move the pointer to the end of the internal array. This worked for me perfectly.

**Relevant code**

```
<?php

class CircularIterator implements Iterator
{
    ...
    ...
    public function next()
    {
        next($this->entries);
        if (!$this->current()) {
            $this->rewind();
        }
    }

    public function prev()
    {
        prev($this->entries);
        if (!$this->current()) {
            $this->end();
        }
    }
  ....
  ....
}
```

full implementation and sample code - [Link](https://gist.github.com/ppshobi/5d4da801fac3be866ea617a5d9637cca)